# How to search a webpage for a keyword with iMacros and highlight the word

Tags: firefox, search, web-scraping, imacros

How to search a webpage for a specific keyword with iMacros (for Firefox) and highlight the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code bellow. It searches the word iMacros withing any element on the page.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:*iMacros*
```

Found the answer here.
http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Testing#Q:_How_can_I_search_for_a_specific_keyword_on_a_web_page.3F

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to highlight a single word in all webpages you visit use this chrome extension Multi-Highlight 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-highlight/pfgfgjlejbbpfmcfjhdmikihihddeeji